# How do I make my keyboard always visible?

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a page that once the user enter, there will be a textfield which allow user to add point, is there anyway I can always allow my keyboard appear without user clicking textfield only appear?

Below images is after I click the textfield it only appear keyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To give focus to a text field as soon as it’s visible, use the autofocus property.

```
TextField(
 autofocus: true,
);
```

So whenever the widget appears on screen, if theres nothing else with the keyboard focus, the focus will automatically be directed to it, thus opening the keyboard.